# How to subset pandas dataframe columns with idxmax output?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,40,size=(10,4)), columns=range(4), index = range(10))
df.head()

    0   1   2   3
0  27  10  13  21
1  25  12  23   8
2   2  24  24  34
3  10  11  11  10
4   0  15   0  27
```

I'm using the `idxmax` function to get the columns that contain the maximum value.

```
df_max = df.idxmax(1)
df_max.head()

0    0
1    0
2    3
3    1
4    3
```

How can I use `df_max` along with `df`, to create a time-series of values corresponding to the maximum value in each row of `df`? This is the output I want:

```
0    27
1    25
2    34
3    11
4    27
5    37
6    35
7    32
8    20
9    38
```

I know I can achieve this using `df.max(1)`, but I want to know how to arrive at this same output by using `df_max`, since I want to be able to apply `df_max` to other matrices (not `df`) which share the same columns and indices as `df` (but not the same values).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try `df.lookup`

```
df.lookup(df_max.index, df_max)

Out[628]: array([27, 25, 34, 11, 27], dtype=int64)
```

If you want Series/DataFrame, you pass the output to the Series/DataFrame constructor

```
pd.Series(df.lookup(df_max.index, df_max), index=df_max.index)

Out[630]:
0    27
1    25
2    34
3    11
4    27
dtype: int64
```

Comment: this is a clean and short one. ie `df.lookup(df.index,df.idxmax(1))`